# Optimize outer loop with OpenMP and a reduction

Tags: c++, c++11, parallel-processing, openmp

I struggle a bit with a function. The calculation is wrong if I try to parallelize the outer loop with a

```
#pragma omp parallel reduction(+:det).
```

Can someone show me how to solve it and why it is failing?

```
// template<class T> using vector2D = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;

float Det(vector2DF &a, int n)
{
  vector2DF m(n - 1, vector1DF(n - 1, 0));

  if (n == 1) return a[0][0];
  if (n == 2) return a[0][0] * a[1][1] - a[1][0] * a[0][1];

  float det = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    int l = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for private(l)
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
    {
      l = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
      {
        if (k == i) continue;
        m[j - 1][l] = a[j][k];
        l++;
      }
    }
    det += std::pow(-1.0, 1.0 + i + 1.0) * a[0][i] * Det(m, n - 1);
  }

  return det;
}
```

Comment: _The calculation is wrong_ And, what is expected output? What is actual output? What steps did you take to try and resolve the problem yourself?

Comment: This was the original version :/ https://pastebin.com/ZJFjAY5T

Comment: All information, necessary to answer your question (or solve your problem) should be present in the question itself, and not some external links, that may expire at an unspecified time. For that reason - I refuse to follow external links.

Comment: Don't write `std::pow(-1.0, 1.0 + i + 1.0) * ...` which is btw the same as `std::pow(-1.0, i) * ...`. Do this with something like `(i%2 == 0 ? 1.0 : -1.0) * ...` or even so: `(i%2 == 0 ? det += ... : det -= ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you parallelize the outer loop, there is a race condition on this line:

```
m[j - 1][l] = a[j][k];
```

Also you likely want a `parallel for reduction` instead of just a `parallel reduction`.

The issue is, that `m` is shared, even though that wouldn't be necessary given that  it is completely overwritten in the inner loop. Always declare variables as locally as possible, this avoids issues with wrongly shared variables, e.g.:

```
float Det(vector2DF &a, int n)
{
  if (n == 1) return a[0][0];
  if (n == 2) return a[0][0] * a[1][1] - a[1][0] * a[0][1];

  float det = 0;
  #pragma omp parallel reduction(+:det)
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    vector2DF m(n - 1, vector1DF(n - 1, 0));
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
    {
      int l = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
      {
        if (k == i) continue;
        m[j - 1][l] = a[j][k];
        l++;
      }
    }
    det += std::pow(-1.0, 1.0 + i + 1.0) * a[0][i] * Det(m, n - 1);
  }
  return det;
}
```

Now that is correct, but since `m` can be expensive to allocate, performance could benefit from not doing it in each and every iteration. This can be done by splitting `parallel` and `for` directives as such:

```
float Det(vector2DF &a, int n)
{
  if (n == 1) return a[0][0];
  if (n == 2) return a[0][0] * a[1][1] - a[1][0] * a[0][1];

  float det = 0;
  #pragma omp parallel reduction(+:det)
  {
    vector2DF m(n - 1, vector1DF(n - 1, 0));
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
      {
        int l = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
          if (k == i) continue;
          m[j - 1][l] = a[j][k];
          l++;
        }
      }
      det += std::pow(-1.0, 1.0 + i + 1.0) * a[0][i] * Det(m, n - 1);
    }
  }
  return det;
}
```

Now you could also just declare `m` as `firstprivate`, but that would assume that the copy constructor makes a completely independent deep-copy and thus make the code more difficult to reason about.

Please be aware that you should always include expected output, actual output and a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).